# JRuby Nokogiri XML builder to_xml wont output newline for sibling elements

Tags: ruby, xml, jruby, nokogiri

**Using JRuby 1.5.6 with nokogiri (1.5.0.beta.3 for JRuby)**

I am trying to build an XML but all sibling elements with no children are being output on the same line. Am I missing something in my to_xml options?

builder.rb

```
require 'Nokogiri'
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root do
    xml.GUID "foo"
    xml.IDInInfoSource "bar"
  end
end
```

desired output

```
<root>
  <GUID>foo</GUID>
  <IDInInfoSource>bar</IDInInfoSource>
</root>
```

generated output

```
<root>
  <GUID>foo</GUID><IDInInfoSource>bar</IDInInfoSource>
</root>
```

Comment: edited to increase simplicity. Previous example was unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
require 'nokogiri'

builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root do
    xml.Entity "xsi:type"=>"ValidEntityTypeForCCOMClass" do
      xml.GUID 'DEADBEEF'
      xml.IDInInfoSource "Hi Mom"
    end
  end
end

puts builder.to_xml
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <root>
#=>   <Entity xsi:type="ValidEntityTypeForCCOMClass">
#=>     <GUID>DEADBEEF</GUID>
#=>     <IDInInfoSource>Hi Mom</IDInInfoSource>
#=>   </Entity>
#=> </root>
```

If it works for you, then please provide a simple, reproducible test case. (Your code above doesn't run due to dependencies on data and libraries that have not been included.)

If it does not work for you, please list your Ruby and Nokogiri versions.

**Edit**: I have confirmed that I see the same no-newline result as the OP when using jRuby 1.5.6 and Nokogiri 1.5.0.beta.4. The same issue does not occur on Ruby 1.9.2 and Nokogiri 1.5.0.beta.4. I assume it's a difference in the behavior of libxml2 versus the pure-Java Nokogiri.

**Edit 2**: I've [filed a Nokogiri bug](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/issue/410) for this. One interesting thing to notice from that bug report: the output of the jRuby version has an extra newline *after the document* not present in others.

Comment: using JRuby with nokogiri (1.5.0.beta.3). This will likely make a difference.